# ajax json parsing to return related values

Tags: json, ajax, api

I am trying to only parse the information related to a certain "market_name" however I cannot seem to figure out how. The api is located at https://stocks.exchange/api2/ticker which displays information related to the entire exchange. I simply need all of the information returned relating to the "market_name" I am searching for such as ETH_BTC

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://stocks.exchange/api2/ticker",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    last = data.last;
    console.log(last);
    $("#btcprice").text(last);
    },
    error: function() {
      //alert("Was unable to get info!");
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the output of console.log(last)? output of data?

Comment: undefined @DavidPartyka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `data` is an array of objects, not a single object.

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://stocks.exchange/api2/ticker",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // find object
        var market = data.find(function (obj) {
            return obj.market_name == 'ETH_BTC';
        });    

        $("#btcprice").text(market.last);
    },
    error: function() {
      //alert("Was unable to get info!");
    }
});
```

Comment: This returns the first ticker result for "last", not related to ETH_BTC

Comment: @JohnLang I made a typo. It should be `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Use array [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter out the record having `market_name` as `ETH_BTC`.

```
array.filter(obj => {
  return obj.market_name == 'ETH_BTC'
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = [{"min_order_amount":"0.00000010","ask":"0.00000017","bid":"0.0000001","last":"0.00000010","lastDayAgo":"0.00000009","vol":"154955.9586604","spread":"0","buy_fee_percent":"0","sell_fee_percent":"0","market_name":"ATR_BTC","market_id":338,"updated_time":1527789301,"server_time":1527789301},{"min_order_amount":"0.00000010","ask":"0.000032","bid":"0.000012","last":"0.00003200","lastDayAgo":"0.000065","vol":"372.5011152","spread":"0","buy_fee_percent":"0","sell_fee_percent":"0","market_name":"ETH_BTC","market_id":35,"updated_time":1527789301,"server_time":1527789301},{"min_order_amount":"0.00000010","ask":"0.00003595","bid":"0.00003","last":"0.00003000","lastDayAgo":"0.00003001","vol":"26.44435669","spread":"0","buy_fee_percent":"0","sell_fee_percent":"0","market_name":"ARDOR_BTC","market_id":262,"updated_time":1527789301,"server_time":1527789301}];

var res = jsonObj.filter(obj => {
  return obj.market_name == 'ETH_BTC'
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://stocks.exchange/api2/ticker",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    var results = [];
    var searchField = "market_name";
    var searchVal = "ETH_BTC";
    for (var i=0 ; i < data.length ; i++)
    {
        if (data[i][searchField] == searchVal) {
            results.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
    $("#btcprice").text(results[0].last);
    },
    error: function() {
      //alert("Was unable to get info!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a simple code in which you find what you want simply just change searchVal statically or dynamically according to your need......